# How to store prompt box value to local storage

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have created a prompt box to accept ,
reject and on hold I need to save the data what I am entering in it to local storage.

```
row_2_data_8.innerHTML = '<button onclick="on Accept(this)" >Accept</button>\n' +
                         '<button onclick="onreject(this)">Reject</button>\t' +
                         '<button onclick="onhold(this)">Onhold</button>';

function onAccept(td) {
  selectedRow = td.parentElement.parentElement;

  var a = prompt("Please enter Remark");

  var v = {
    "status": a
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [documentation and examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use an LocalStorage Object. So you will do like this :

```
function onAccept(td) {
  selectedRow = td.parentElement.parentElement;

  var a = prompt("Please enter Remark");

  var v = {
    "status": a
  }

  save( v );
}

const save = (v) => { window.localStorage.setItem(v);}
```